# Como hacer render al formulario desde el template y verlo en admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

**Estoy usando Django 1.11.4,**

**root app**

```
 url(r'^contacto/', include('contacto.urls'), name='contacto'),
```

**contacto_app/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from contacto.views import contacto

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', contacto, name='contacto'),
]
```

**contacto_app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class formulario(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=25)
    telefono = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    mensaje = forms.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**contacto_app/views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from.models import Contacto


def contacto(request):
    contactos = Contacto.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'contacto.html', {'contactos': contactos})
```

**contacto_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Contacto(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mensaje = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**template/contacto.html**

```
<body>
  <form action="/contacto/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Al hacer runserver obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Terminal**

[07/May/2018 23:35:42] "POST /contacto/ HTTP/1.1" 200 472

No encuentro la solución,solo quiero que cargue el formulario en el html, y esa información la pueda ver en admin. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando la respuesta que ya te dieron, paso a explicarte un poco más a fondo que quieres y qué necesitas.

Lo primero es empezar por tu formulario, así como te recomiendan, es mejor heredar de la clase `forms.ModelForm` porque de esta forma, se puede generar un formulario de acuerdo a una clase, y tendrás a tu disposición un método `save` para guardar directamente en la tabla del modelo que le asignes a ese formulario, quedando tu formulario de la siguiente forma:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contacto

class ContactoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacto
        fields = ('nombre', 'email', 'telefono', 'mensaje', )
```

Para tener en cuenta, cada campo que agregues en la propiedad `fields`, debe estar contenida dentro de tu modelo (en el archivo *models.py*, dentro de la clase). Y serán del mismo tipo de datos que especifiques en el modelo.

Lo siguiente es en tu vista, para que pueda renderizar bien el formulario, es importante que le pases las variables de contexto a los templates. La función shortcut `render` acepta 3 parámetros, el primero: la petición; Segundo: la ruta en *string* del template a renderizar, y el tercero: son la variables que usará ese template (el contexto). Es decir, cualquier variable que vayas a pasar a tu template, debe estar dentro de este diccionario de variables, por lo que si quieres pasar tu formulario y renderizarlo, deberías hacer algo como esto:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Contacto
from .forms import ContactoForm

def contacto(request):
    contactos = Contacto.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = ContactoForm(data=request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
    else:
        formulario = ContactoForm()

    return render(request, 'contacto.html', {'contactos': contactos, 'form': formulario})
```

De esta forma ya debe renderizar. Y por último, si quieres que ese formulario sea el mismo que se ve en el administrador de Django. Hay un archivo que se genera automáticamente cuando creamos una app con `manage.py` y ese archivo se llama *admin.py* donde se supone que debemos de llevar las clases y funciones relacionadas con el admin para nuestra app.

Para que tu formulario se vea reflejado en el admin, asegúrate de tener esto en el admin

**admin.py**

```
from . import models, forms
from django.contrib import admin

class ContactoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.ContactoForm

admin.site.register(models.Contacto, ContactoAdmin)
```

De esta forma tu formulario debería verse también en el formulario cuando haces algo con el administrador

**EDITO**

Agrego en la vista la forma como debes tratar tu formulario, de tal forma que cuando llega por el método POST el lo valida y si todo está correcto, lo guarda en la base de datos para que posteriormente puedas verlo desde el admin

Comment: Muy buen  aporte aclare varias dudas. Ahora el problema es al enviar desde el template no los sube al admin ni los carga en la base de datos,he modificado varias cosas y nada, pregunta tengo que modificar algo ** <form action="/contacto/"> **  No carga los datos desde el html a la BD y el terminal   la info es: ** /contacto/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4644**

Comment: @Developer he editado la respuesta añadiendo lo que necesitas para tratar los formularios en Django

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estoy viendo en ningún punto le estás pasando la variable form.

Cambia el `form.Form` por `form.ModelForm` en tu clase formulario. Ahí puedes usar la clase `Meta` e incluir el modelo que quieres usar.

También debes cargar el formulario en tu funcion contacto e incluirla en el render como estas incluyendo contactos.

Si esa información la quieres ver dentro de `/admin/` lo que debes de crear una clase `ModelAdmin` dentro de tu archivo admin.py